# How to Calculate the Time difference when IGN is On to OFF using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame which has IGN column and Time column i want to calculate the time difference where IGN On to IGN OFF
here is my script
import pandas as pd

```
data = {'IGN': ['On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'Off', 'Off', 'Off', 'On', 'Off', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'Off'], 'Time': ['08-06-2023 10:05:56 AM', '08-06-2023 10:06:49 AM', '08-06-2023 10:06:52 AM', '08-06-2023 10:07:08 AM', '08-06-2023 10:07:16 AM', '08-06-2023 10:07:19 AM', '08-06-2023 10:07:33 AM', '08-06-2023 10:07:56 AM', '08-06-2023 10:12:33 AM', '08-06-2023 10:13:55 AM', '08-06-2023 10:13:56 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:07 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:10 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:13 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:23 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:31 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:34 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:37 AM', '08-06-2023 10:14:40 AM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

here IGN is On at 0th row and Off at 6th row here 0 to 6 one cycle and i want to find the time difference in this cycle and again IGN On at 9th row and Off at 10th this is the second cycle
here is the expected output
0   0 days 00:01:37
1   0 days 00:00:01
2   0 days 00:00:33
i want to consider only On duration how much time the IGN is On
can anyone help me thorough this thanks and regards

Comment: not directly related to your Question, but beware - with only one instance seen, is it possible your signal greatly exceeds your collection rate and you can miss some? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate

Comment: Do you want the output to be two sequential outputs as text or do you expect this output in some form of dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift the IGN so we can compare if the IGN switched. This let's us filter down to only the rows where it was either the first row or it was a switch row. Assuming we start on, then even rows are on rows and odd rows are off rows, so we just subtract even from odd rows to get our time diff.

```
Prev_IGN = df["IGN"].shift(1)
Changed = df["IGN"] != Prev_IGN

switches = df[Changed].reset_index(drop=True)

time_diffs = switches[1::2].reset_index()['Time'] - switches[::2].reset_index()['Time']

print(time_diffs)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. this script also worked

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not most efficient way to do but Yeah this will work

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'IGN': ["On", "On", "On", "On", "Off", "On", "Off"],
    'Time': ["2023-06-08 17:11:25", "2023-06-08 17:11:36", "2023-06-08 17:11:49", "2023-06-08 17:11:55", "2023-06-08 17:12:02", "2023-06-08 17:12:05", "2023-06-08 17:13:05"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])


i = 0

while i<len(df):
    if(df["IGN"][i] == "On"):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if(df["IGN"][j] == "Off"):
                print("Time Difference:", df["Time"][j] - df["Time"][i])
                i = j
                break
    i+=1
```

Output

```
Time Difference: 0 days 00:00:37
Time Difference: 0 days 00:01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is to assign an arbitrary sequence id for each group of On-Off sequence using the cumsum and shift. Then use this id as the grouping key and use the
built-in aggregators (min and max). From the resulting dataframe get the difference between the min/max time.

```
>>> df['seq_id'] = ((df['IGN'] == 'On') & (df['IGN'].shift() == 'Off')).cumsum()
>>> grouped = df.groupby('seq_id')['Time'].agg(['min','max']).reset_index()
>>> grouped['diff'] = grouped['max'] - grouped['min']
>>> grouped['diff']
0   0 days 00:00:37
1   0 days 00:01:00
Name: diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Note that if the original dataframe has consecutive "Off" entries, this solution will consider them as part of the same group and thus will get the latest "Off" Time entry before getting the difference.

Comment: this code is taking first group of ON as well as Off but the code has to consider all On duration and only consider first occurrence of OFF duration i edited my question can you check once